# Add class to sibling divs using a number to determine the amount of divs to add class to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to the siblings of a nested  div depndant on the length of a scope attached to the dom in itself, for the purpouse of demonstration i have just declared a variable with a number assigned to it, so here is my current js:

```
    var countdates = $('.date').length;
var minstay = 5;
alert(countdates);
$('.date').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('dateset' + minstay);
});
```

and here is a example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/ujUZb/1/) basically my question is if i click on a div i want the next 5 divs to have a class added to them even if they span across the nested divs??

I have tried to google this but i can't seem to get the terminology right.

Answer (score 2):

Get the index of the current one, add the `minstay`, and use a selector that selects everything inbetween ?

```
var minstay = 5;

$('.date').on('click', function () {
    var start = $(this).index('.date'),
        end   = start + minstay;

    $('.date:lt('+end+'):gt('+(start-1)+')').addClass('dateset');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujUZb/4/)